# unable to perform Delete operation on Odata services using s4sdk

Tags: s4sdk

I followed the blog & I was able to perform create, read  & update operations on my custom OData service, but I am unable to find any blog/document for delete operation.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no dedicated blog post for executing delete operations on custom OData Services but we would advise you to follow this pattern:

```java
public class DeleteAddressCommand extends ErpCommand<Integer> {
    private static final Logger logger = CloudLoggerFactory.getLogger(DeleteAddressCommand.class);

    private final BusinessPartnerService service;
    private final String businessPartnerId;
    private final String addressId;

    public DeleteAddressCommand(final BusinessPartnerService service,
                                final String businessPartnerId, final String addressId) {
        super(HystrixUtil.getDefaultErpCommandSetter(
                DeleteAddressCommand.class,
                HystrixUtil.getDefaultErpCommandProperties().withExecutionTimeoutInMilliseconds(10000)));

        this.service = service;
        this.businessPartnerId = businessPartnerId;
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer run() throws Exception {
        final BusinessPartnerAddress addressToDelete = BusinessPartnerAddress.builder()
                .businessPartner(businessPartnerId)
                .addressID(addressId)
                .build();

        final ODataDeleteResult oDataDeleteResult = service
                .deleteBusinessPartnerAddress(addressToDelete)
                .execute();

        return oDataDeleteResult.getHttpStatusCode();
    }
}
```

I pasted the code from [this official example](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-book/blob/master/application/src/main/java/com/sap/cloud/s4hana/examples/addressmgr/commands/DeleteAddressCommand.java)

Best wishes
Florian